# Scalar-Vector multiplication with meshgrid (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, vectorization, linear-algebra

I have an expression such as s=aU+bV, where `a` and `b` are scalars and `U` and `V` 3-component vectors. The output `s` is clearly a 3-component vector. Let's assume I want to plot the first component of `s` find out how this varies when I change `a` and `b`.

In order to plot I have to use surf, which takes matrices for the variables `a` `b`. So I attempt to create matrices with `meshgrid`:

```
A=0:10;
B=1:10;
[a,b]=meshgrid(A,B);

U=[1,1,0];
V=[1,0,1];

s = a*U + b*V;
```

This clearly doesn't work, because nor the matrix product nor the element-wise product are well defined in this case. How do I actually make the matrices which represent the grid `a` `b` multiply element-by-element the vectors `U` and `V`?

Comment: But if you only want to examine the first component of `s`, all you need to do is use the first component of `U` and `V`. Why complicate things?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I would imagine that they're just using that as an example, and will want to examine all of the components separately.

Comment: @MrAzzaman That's right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use element-wise multiplication (`.*`) because you still want to treat `a` and `b` as scalars (i.e. use each element individually).

You can make a 3D output, where each 2D slice corresponds to your `meshgrid` output, with one slice per component of `U` and `V`. Therefore in this example getting a `10*11*3` matrix.

To do this, just `reshape` the `U` and `V` vectors to be `1*1*3` in size

```
U = reshape( [1,1,0], 1, 1, [] ); % Or equivalently U(1,1,:) = [1,1,0]
V = reshape( [1,0,1], 1, 1, [] ); % Or equivalently U(1,1,:) = [1,0,1]
```

Then do element-wise multiplication

```
s = a.*U + b.*V;
```

Note: before MATLAB R2016b (when implicit expansion was introduced) you'll have to use `bsxfun` to get the equivalent:

```
s = bsxfun( @times, a, U ) + bsxfun( @times, b, V );
```

You can then plot the `i`th element of `S` changing with `A` and `B` by plotting `s(:,:,i)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using a 3D matrix:

```
[A,B] = meshgrid(0:10,1:10);
U(1,1,:) = [1,1,0];
V(1,1,:) = [1,0,1];
s = A.*U + B.*V;
% s is now a NxMx3 matrix, where N = length(A) and M = length(B)

% We can plot how s varies with a and b as follows
surf(A,B,s(:,:,1)); % first component
surf(A,B,s(:,:,2)); % second component
surf(A,B,s(:,:,3)); % third component
```